# PHP foreach filtered by condition

Tags: php, arrays

I have multidimensional array with results and I would like to filter these based on given category. Just like we would do with “WHERE” in MySQL.

```
<?php 
$links_cat = 1;
foreach($linkcreator as $x=>$link)
  {
  echo "Category: " . $link[0] . " - <a href='" . $link[1] . "'>" . $link[2] , "</a>";
  echo "<br>";
  }
?>
```

`$links_cat` is corresponding with `$link[0]`. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an **if statement**

```
<?php 
$links_cat = 1;
foreach($linkcreator as $x=>$link)
{
    if($link[0] == $links_cat){
        echo "Category: " . $link[0] . " - <a href='" . $link[1] . "'>" . $link[2] , "</a>";
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
?>
```